# Qual o peso de uma subquery para a consulta?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Durante o desenvolvimento de algumas consultas no banco de dados, me deparo com a situação da necessidade de realizar uma nova consulta, mas outra solução em alguns casos pode ser a subquery.

Então qual é a melhor solução realizar uma segunda consulta ou utilizar subquery em situações assim? Qual o peso de uma subquery para minha consulta? É válido a ponto de não precisar fazer uma nova consulta no banco?

Comment: Depende da situação, depende de como a subquery é construída. Não sei se existe alguma ferramenta para análise de estratégia de busca com mysql... De qualquer forma, uma subquery **é** uma nova consulta, e de acordo com a forma que é utilizada, pode gerar uma ou mais consultas ao banco **para cada registro da *query* principal**.

Comment: Depende também da existência de índices, estatíscas atualizadas etc. Em alguns casos o uso de um "outer join" é mais rápido.

Comment: Tudo indexado, na maioria dessas situações o outer join não resolvem a situação, geralmente existe a necessidade da subquery ou segunda query.

Comment: Em alguns casos uma "desnormalização" pode ajudar , imagine o seguinte cenário cliente x saldo devedor , em tese seria preciso uma subquery ou join para saber isto, mas se uma coluna em cliente for atualizada por triggers o peso desta consulta cai pois basta acessar cliente, a questão é pesar o custo de triggers x custo das consultas.

Comment: Eu tento ao máximo não fazer subquery pelo fator performático e aprendi a fazer SQL otimizadas que trazem o mesmo resultado e mais rápido. Tudo vai depender de como ta o seu banco pra mim sendo o ponto crucial (falta de indices, tabelas sem relacionamentos, bancos sem normalização, etc.).

Comment: A resposta exata você só vai obter dando um `EXPLAIN` na query e analisando o resultado. Depende muito do caso.

Answer (score 1):

Entre obter o resultado por meio de uma subquery ou realizar uma segunda consulta, a subquery em condições normais será menos custosa por que não redunda a execução dos algoritmos de comunicação entre o **client** e o **server**. No entanto, é preciso considerar que para cada linha da consulta principal, a subquery será executada; Portanto, você precisa pesar se de fato faria isoladamente a mesma quantidade de consultas.

O real peso de uma subquery depende dos algoritmos do seu SGDB e da modelagem do seu Banco. Essa é uma resposta impossível de se dar sem analisar a sua estrutura.

Meu conselho final é que, se possível, substitua as subquerys por Joins. Isso sim otimizará a performance e, em minha experiencia, isso quase sempre é possível (e não esqueça dos índices).